# How to run docker-compose with php-fpm and php-cli?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I need to run docker-compose with two containers,- php-fpm and php-cli. Although I need another container with composer.

When I run docker-compose up -d - container with php-cli become always restarting and composer container just stops.

Comment: why do you use restart: always in php? why dont you run composer in "travellizy_php"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP cli is not running in daemon mode. You run it, and then it stops. Next, Docker tries to restart it (you've set `restart: always` policy for `php-cli`). :)

IMO `php-cli` and `composer` services are redundant. You can use `php` service for your needs. Simply run `docker-compose run php php [path to script]`

Comment: "IMO php-cli and composer services are redundant. You can use php service for your needs." Not disagreeing, but why do you believe this? What's the difference between Docker `php`, Docker `php-cli` and Docker `php-fpm`, see also question, here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/what-is-the-difference-between-php-cli-and-php-fpm-why-2-php-variants-and-why-c

Comment: @therobyouknow the `php-fpm` docker image can handle all of the required things: running script in CLI mode and running composer (ie via the phar archive).